# Why isn't CSS and Javascript recognized when executing from python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I'm currently building a website using Django and I've noticed that whenever I execute `python manage.py runserver` the CSS and Javascript isn't working at all. The HTML is working perfectly but somehow the CSS and JS doesn't get recognized at all.

However, when I open the HTML file, the CSS and JS works perfectly, so there is nothing wrong with the CSS and JS files. Somehow it doesn't get recognized when I run the server from python.

Is there a reason for this?

Here is some code:

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

from chatterbot import ChatBot

# Create your views here.
chatbot = ChatBot(
    'Ron Obvious',
    trainer='chatterbot.trainers.ChatterBotCorpusTrainer'
)

@csrf_exempt
def get_response(request):
    response = {'status': None}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        message = data['message']

        chat_response = chatbot.get_response(message).text
        response['message'] = {'text': chat_response, 'user': False, 'chat_bot': True}
        response['status'] = 'ok'

    else:
        response['error'] = 'no post data found'

    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(response),
            content_type="application/json"
        )

def Index (request):
    context = {'title': 'Chatbot Version 1.0'}

    return render(request, "AI.html", context)
```

Settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

project_root = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATIC_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(project_root, 'static'),
)
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'MyApp',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'MySite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'MySite.wsgi.application'
```

Here is how the maps are organized 
[image]

I get the following error message in devtools:

> Refused to apply style from
>   'http://127.0.0.1:8000/MySite/MySite/static/css/AI.css' because its
>   MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and
>   strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: What do you see in your browser's devtools? Any messages in the console? Any non-200 responses in the network tab?

Comment: @Chris Yeah it says **Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/MySite/MySite/static/css/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.**

Comment: That's the kind of thing that you should always include in the question when you first ask it. In the future, please do.

Comment: @Chris Alright, I will. Thank you

Comment: Grab this url and open it manually in the browser. My guess is: some of your url patterns handles this url and returns an html page instead of static file. So show urls.py if you still need any assistance.

Comment: How are u accessing the css and js files? Are they linked by html?